# Combining Rows in MS Access SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, grouping

Below I have a screenshot of a query in MS Access. I am trying to combine the two "Kim Wong" rows into one row that has one time range in the `Monday` column and the other time range in the `Tuesday` column. There will when done have time ranges in each of the cells.

[image]

Here is what the query looks like.

[image]

And here is the actual code

```
SELECT qryEmployed.EmployeeName, First(IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",0,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")) AS Monday, First(IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",1,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")) AS Tuesday, First(IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",2,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")) AS Wednesday, First(IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",3,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")) AS Thursday, First(IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",4,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")) AS Friday, First(IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",5,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")) AS Saturday, First(IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",6,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")) AS Sunday
FROM tblEvents INNER JOIN qryEmployed ON tblEvents.Employee = qryEmployed.EmployeeName
GROUP BY qryEmployed.EmployeeName, qryEmployed.Position, tblEvents.Event, tblEvents.EventDate, tblEvents.StartTime, tblEvents.EndTime, tblEvents.Lunch, IIf([Event]="Scheduled",((IIf([EndTime]<[StartTime],1,0)+[EndTime])-[StartTime]-IIf([Lunch],1/48,0))*24,0)
HAVING (((tblEvents.EventDate)=DateAdd("d",0,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]))) OR (((tblEvents.EventDate)=DateAdd("d",1,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]))) OR (((tblEvents.EventDate)=DateAdd("d",2,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]))) OR (((tblEvents.EventDate)=DateAdd("d",3,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]))) OR (((tblEvents.EventDate)=DateAdd("d",4,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]))) OR (((tblEvents.EventDate)=DateAdd("d",5,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]))) OR (((tblEvents.EventDate)=DateAdd("d",6,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate])));
```

Here is a sample of `tblEmployees`.
 [image]

Here is the `qryEmployed`.
[image]

And here is the `tblEvents`.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with hdizzle, your query is incredibly hard to read because it seems it was generated from the MS Access GUI. I highly suggest you avoid the GUI and learn SQL syntax directly.

Your query is essentially aggregating among multiple values that return if the individual has a value for each day. You need to 'group by' all returned columns that are not being aggregated.

I re-formatted the query a bit and I removed all of the extraneous GROUP BY clauses that I don't believe do anything. Then I added an aggregate clause to each 'DayOfTheWeek' return column. The query below should return the time an event occurred for the individual if an event occurred or it should return a blank. If multiple events occurred, it would return the last one alphabetically (you never explained how you wanted that scenario to be handled).

Further, you are linking on the name field, I highly suggest you link on an ID field. Names change relatively often and I am fairly sure linking on an integer has better performance.

Try something like

```
SELECT qryEmployed.EmployeeName, 
MAX(First(
    IIf(EventDate)]=DateAdd("d",0,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]), IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")
)) AS Monday,
MAX(First(
    IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",1,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")
)) AS Tuesday,
MAX(First(
    IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",2,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")
)) AS Wednesday, 
MAX(First(
    IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",3,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")
)) AS Thursday,
MAX(First(
    IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",4,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")
)) AS Friday, 
MAX(First(
    IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",5,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")
)) AS Saturday, 
MAX(First(
    IIf([EventDate]=DateAdd("d",6,[Forms]![tblEvents]![tbxDate]),IIf([Event]="Scheduled",Format([StartTime],"h:nn") & " - " & Format([EndTime],"h:nn"),[Event]),"")
)) AS Sunday
FROM tblEvents INNER JOIN qryEmployed ON tblEvents.Employee = qryEmployed.EmployeeName
GROUP BY 
qryEmployed.EmployeeName
```

Comment: This was what I needed. I had to make a few small changes, but it was right.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell based on all the gunk that access is throwing in your actual sql, but I believe that you are getting this issue because you are starting your query with the Event table and then joining into the qryEmployed table.  Joining in that fashion is creating two rows because Kim Wong is assigned to two different events, hence her name gets entered onto two different rows.  You need to drop the Event column from your table as a start, that will likely fix it.

If you could show the whole table returned or at least the query tables it would go a long way in helping further diagnose what to change.

Comment: Removing the event column didn't work. What do you mean show the whole table?

Comment: @Makai Without seeing the actual data or at least some sample data in the same format, it's hard to tell exactly what is going on with your data. Especially because you have a GROUP BY satement in  your query.  For example, I'm assuming that your relationship between EmployeeName and Employee is 1:many because of the way your resulting table looks, but without you telling me explicitly or me being able to look at a sample of your data tables, it makes it hard to diagnose what is going on.